# SQL Self Join combining collections

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, self-join

I am looking for all the records for CollA and CollB. I also want to pre-append the base records to each collection, at the same time retarding the sequence numbers of the base collection by 3 (a static number the query doesn't have to count the rows) so that when sorted the base rows appear first.

I have tried searching for queries similar but haven't found anything. Mostly I think, because I can't come up with the technical name for what it is I am trying to do. Is there a name for this sort of thing?

The query I have that does not include the base records looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NamedFieldCollections 
WHERE CollectionName IN (SELECT CollectionName FROM NamedCollections)

CollectionName | FieldName | Sequence
-----------------------------------------------
CollA            Field1      0
CollA            Field2      1
CollA            Field3      2
CollB            FieldA      0
CollB            FieldB      1
Base             F1          0
Base             F2          1
Base             F3          2
```

I am trying to end up with a query where the results look like this:

```
CollectionName | FieldName | Sequence
-----------------------------------------------
CollA            F1          -3
CollA            F2          -2
CollA            F3          -1
CollA            Field1      0
CollA            Field2      1
CollA            Field3      2
CollB            F1          -3
CollB            F2          -2
CollB            F3          -1
CollB            FieldA      0
CollB            FieldB      1
```

Comment: Did you try `order by collectionName, FieldName`?

Comment: where did you get this strange looking table from ? Is this some kind of mapping table for which sort of links different tables columns ?

Comment: The fields are used to describe other property tables. (CollectionName refers to the name of a table, and FieldName are it's columns.) Every table has the same base columns, but each table has it's own unique columns as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CollectionName, FieldName, Sequence
FROM 
(
    SELECT T1.CollectionName, T1.FieldName, T1.Sequence
    FROM NamedFieldCollections T1
    WHERE T1.CollectionName <> 'Base'
    UNION
    SELECT T3.CollectionName, T2.FieldName, T2.Sequence - 3
    FROM NamedFieldCollections T2
    CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT DISTINCT T4.CollectionName 
         FROM NamedFieldCollections T4 
         WHERE T4.CollectionName <> 'Base'
    ) T3
    WHERE T2.CollectionName = 'Base'
) T
ORDER BY T.CollectionName, T.Sequence
```

Comment: The first answer to take all factors into consideration.

Comment: This is what I had in mind too. Was also considering using something like `Sequence - COUNT(*) OVER ()` because I'd overlooked the bit where it said that rows needn't be counted. Note that `UNION` will attempt to exclude duplicate rows, which implies some unnecessary (in this case) overhead, like sorting. `UNION ALL` doesn't do that and would be perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM NamedFieldCollections 
WHERE CollectionName IN (SELECT CollectionName FROM NamedCollections)
order by collectionName, FieldName;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Sorry, that wont really help. I just selects the rows for CollA and CollB. If you look more closely, you will see that my desired output has 3 more rows than the table contains. The results should contain a complete set of the rows where CollectionName = 'Base' for each of the other 2 unique [CollectionName]s (CollA and CollB).

Answer (score 0):

please check this as you want..

```
declare @t table(CollectionName  varchar(50), FieldName varchar(50), Sequence int)

insert into @t values ('CollA','Field1','0'),('CollA','Field2','1'),('CollA','Field3','2')
,('CollB','FieldA','0'),('CollB','FieldB','1'),('Base','F1','0'),
('Base','F2','1'),('Base','F3','2')

select * from 
(
    select  case when CollectionName = 'Base' then 'CollA' end CollectionName,
            FieldName, Sequence-3 Sequence
    from @t NamedFieldCollections2 
    where NamedFieldCollections2.CollectionName like 'BASE'
    union 
    select * from @t NamedFieldCollections2 
    where NamedFieldCollections2.CollectionName like 'CollA'
) a
union all
select * from 
(
    select  case when CollectionName = 'Base' then 'CollB' end CollectionName,
            FieldName, Sequence-3 Sequence
    from @t NamedFieldCollections2 
    where NamedFieldCollections2.CollectionName like 'BASE'
    union 
    select * from @t NamedFieldCollections2 
    where NamedFieldCollections2.CollectionName like 'CollB'
) a

Result will be
CollectionName  FieldName   Sequence
CollA           F1          -3
CollA           F2      -2
CollA           F3      0
CollA           Field1      0
CollA           Field2          1
CollA           Field3      2
CollB           F1      -3
CollB           F2      -2
CollB           F3      -1
CollB           FieldA          0
CollB           FieldB          1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And it works, it does everything but retard the sequence numbers.
'   select distinct a.CollectionName, b.FieldName, b.Sequence - 3 as Sequence
    from @t a
     INNER JOIN @t b ON b.CollectionName = 'Base'
    where a.CollectionName IN ('CollA', 'CollB')
    union
    select a.CollectionName, a.FieldName, a.Sequence
    from @t a
    where a.CollectionName IN ('CollA', 'CollB')
    order by a.CollectionName, a.Sequence'

Comment: where you stuck. please explain what you want with sequence no.

Comment: I always want the FieldNames belonging to the 'Base' CollectionName to be displayed first.